# TypeError: decoding str is not supported while iterating over a list of tuples python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a list of tuples

```
a = [('BC', 'CONTAINS'), ('CD', 'FREE_FROM'), ('BM', 'CONTAINS') , ('ZZ', nan), (nan, nan), (nan, 'FREE_FROM'), (nan, nan)]
```

I want a list which does not contain any nan and also does not contain element in which second element of tuple is 'FREE_FROM' such that the resulting list looks like the following:

```
res = [('BC', 'CONTAINS'),  ('BM', 'CONTAINS')]
```

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
res = [(x,y) for x,y in containsAllergen if (str(x,y) != ('nan', 'nan') or str(y) != 'FREE_FROM')]
```

but it is throwing the error mentioned in the subject:

```
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What type is ```nan```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in :

```
str(x,y)
```

Beside, I think you will need the "and" operator to produce the result you need:

```
res = [(x,y) for x,y in a if (str(x) != 'nan' and str(y) != 'nan' and str(y) != 'FREE_FROM')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) operator to check for `nan` and use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract the second item for comparison.

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [('BC', 'CONTAINS'), ('CD', 'FREE_FROM'), ('BM', 'CONTAINS') , ('ZZ', nan), (nan, nan), (nan, 'FREE_FROM'), (nan, nan)]
>>> second_item = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> [t for t in a if second_item(t) != 'FREE_FROM' and nan not in t]
[('BC', 'CONTAINS'), ('BM', 'CONTAINS')]
>>>
```